# How to print line of Text file if Semicolon is at the end

Tags: python

I have a text file.

**Test.txt**

```
this is line one; this line one

this is line two;

this is line three
```

I want to print line which contains  semicolon but the semicolon should be at the end of line.

**My code**

```
search =  open("Test.txt","r")
for line in search :
    if ";" in line:
        semi = line.split(";")
        if semi[-1] == "\n":
             print(line)
```

**Output**

```
this is line two;
```

My code is working fine but i want a better way to do this.
Can any one tell me short and most pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure its easier

```
for line in search :
    if line.endswith(';\n'):
        print(line)
```

And as [`@IMCoins`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47864395/3124746) noted it's better to use context manager `with` to close your file when you're done working:

```
with open("Test.txt","r") as test_file:
    for line in test_file:
        if line.endswith(';\n'):
            print(line)
```

Comment: @sam yes, i've tested it.

Comment: thanks ....now this code is working fine and i think this the shortest way to do it

Comment: I'd advise you to be careful about 'short code'. The shorter, is not the better. However, The clearer the better. :)

Comment: The slice notation in ShpielMeister's answer would also work here because it is "obvious" that `';\n'` is two characters long - but anything longer *needs* `endswith`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `with` keyword at first to open a file :

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ';' in line:
            semi = line.split(';')
            if semi[-1] == '\n':
                print line
```

For me, it is already mostly pythonic as you're using built-in function, with `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if line[:-2] == ';\n':
    print(line)
```

works correctly for python 2 & 3
also works if line is only a '/n'

Comment: Although this may answer the questions, you may wan't to provide some extra details and explain the answer. In it's current state this answer is low-quality.